# Select element not followed by another

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to be able to select an HTML **p** tag , ONLY if it is not followed by another **div** element with particular class. For example, I will need to select this **P**

```
<div id="myContainer">
    <p>...</p>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

but not this, because it is followed by a div with class="red".

```
<div id="myContainer">
    <p>...</p>
    <div class="red">...</div>
</div>
```

Here's what I'm attempting:

```
#myContainer > p ~ div:not(.step)
```

Comment: Which part is not possible? I've used ~ before to select elements following something.

Comment: From what I understand in your question, you want to select a previous elements. In the future, you might be able to use `!p + div:not(.step)` Take a look at this http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject

Comment: I'm not trying to select previous. I select current, IF it's not followed by an element with the class.

Comment: @santa - You wrote that you want to "select an HTML p tag [..]". All given answers are wrong -- all of them select div-elements.

Comment: In the solution by @JoshCrozier, [`!` was replaced by `:has`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational)

Comment: @JoshCrozier it has been 9 years and the future is coming :) it works onChrome and will be release in the next version of  Firefox!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Is this what you mean? Then you're almost there.

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/9bL2j/)

```css
/* will select p not directly followed by div.red */
#myContainer > p + div:not(.red)
```

Comment: @santa But [it doesn't select](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/9bL2j/1/) the `<p>` element, but the adjacent `<div>` not having class of `.red`.

Comment: @HashemQolami oh you're right! Santa, could you verify that this is (not) exactly what you need?

Comment: You're selecting the div not the p

Answer (score 3):

### Update in 2023:

It is now **possible** to use the `:has()` ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)) pseudo-class as a way of selecting a **parent element** or a **previous sibling element** with respect to a reference element by taking a relative selector list as an argument.

Note that some browsers may still not support this.
As of this writing, Chrome and Safari already support this. With Firefox, it's in development and is supported in a pre-release version.

So the following will achieve what the question is asking:

```
.myContainer p:has(+ div:not(.red)) {
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
```

**DEMO** https://jsfiddle.net/fzya5eLd/

---

### Original answer in 2014:

You can't use CSS to target previous elements, but based on your HTML structure you can use immediate sibling selector.

CSS:

```
.myContainer p + div:not(.red)   {
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="myContainer">
    <p>...</p>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
<div class="myContainer">
    <p>...</p>
    <div class="red">...</div>
</div>
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/92VVZ/

Comment: This selects the `div` element, not the `p` element like the OP asked, right?

Comment: @robertspierre I have updated the answer with 2023 info, the original answer was from 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myContainer">
      <p>P1</p>
      <div>D1</div>
  </div>
  <div id="myContainer">
      <p>P2</p>
      <div class="red">D2</div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSS selector:

```
p:not(:has(+div.red))
```

will select the first `p` but not the last one.

Explanation:

- The `:not()` pseudo-class represents an element that is not represented by its argument ([link](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#negation))
- The `:has()` pseudo-class ([link](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#relational)) represents an element that matches the selector in its argument when anchored against that element. This pseudo-class works since Chrome >= 105 (released august 30, 2022) while, as of December 2023, it has yet to be released in Firefox([link](https://caniuse.com/css-has))
- The next-sibling combinator `+` selects the next sibling of an element ([link](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#adjacent-sibling-combinators))

All other answers are wrong as they select the `div` element, not the previous `p` element.